# Redirect to a page with a Japanese character parameter using webapp2

Tags: python, redirect, unicode, webapp2

In my webapp I want to redirect from a POST to a GET to another URL and set a parameter for the GET as a Japanese character.

This works:

```
self.redirect("SomePage?param=%s" % "value")
```

This raises an encoding error inside redirect:

```
self.redirect("SomePage?param=%s" % u"が")
```

Is there any way to redirect and set that Japanese character parameter for the redirect-to page?

Comment: what error exactly do you get? stacktrace? what if you try `self.redirect("SomePage?param=%s" % u"が".encode('utf_8')`

Comment: Then it simply doesn't redirect to anywhere. It won't raise an error either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query string should be both encoded as 'utf-8', and [percent-encoded](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode):

```
>>> import urllib
>>> 'SomePage?%s' % urllib.urlencode({'param': u'が'.encode('utf-8')})
'SomePage?param=%E3%81%8C'
```